# Comma in kubectl used as a pipe

Tags: kubernetes

Have you seen a comma in a `kubectl` command?

Like the following command:

```
kubectl get deployments,ing -n my-system
```

Is it like a pipe grap or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a separator between k8s resources, that you would like to do something with (get/describe/etc...). Your command will output the list of `Ingress` resources next to the list of `Deployments`